# Docusign: IP addresses for DocuSign REST API service

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking for the range of IP addresses for the Docusign REST API service.  I manage an app that uses the REST API and in the past few days we have gotten responses from IPs that were not in the ranges that we got from docusign when this was implemented a few years ago.

I couldn't easily find this on the docusign site, although I found a few outdated links.
https://www.docusign.com/trust/alerts/update-102918-updated-ip-addresses-for-docusign-service

Is there a good resource for this information or is there an updated methodology for security that we should implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is in the bottom of this page - https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature

I'm sorry you found an outdated page.
I rather not write IP addresses here as they can change, better to check the link above.

Comment: Thanks!  You answered this faster than docusign support